# PIM Integrated with Magento Using Customizable Options NOT Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, product, products-management, data, customizable-options

I'm looking for PIM or some product data management tool that integrates with a Magento 2 store and utilizes the customizable options (sometimes 30+ options per base SKU), NOT one that uses the configurable products setup found in Magento.

I've only found out-of-the-box PIMs that use the configurable product function. Many customizable options seem to be a stumbling block for all the PIMs I've tried to work with.

For example, we have products with a base SKU, 5 customizable options that a choice is required for, and 30 customizable options that they can add in many different iterations.  This equates to millions of possible SKUs that can be created.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at PIMCore's Enterprise Edition:  https://pimcore.com/en/platform/enterprise-edition
I use it for a few of my clients with huge & complicated catalogs.

Comment: Thank you Ahmad.  I previously reached out to them but never received a response.  I'll try again.

Comment: Feel free to let me know if you need any help contacting them.